# Reload div with same content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

I've a div  which contains a  list of clients pulled from Mysql.

On the same page I have a jquery dialog box which pops up to allow a user to add a new client.

What I want to happen is that when the user adds a new client the  containing the list reloads so the new client is available.

Is there a way to simply reload the div without using the Load() function as this is causing errors when I redeclare my classes that populate the list ?

Comment: Yes, use the underlying $.ajax method that .load uses. however, .load would likely be easier.

Comment: Please provide samples of what you've already tried.

Comment: Do you have to add the new client to the database? If not, you can just create the element with jquery and append it to the DOM

Comment: Are you retreiving user's info from an ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Without looking at your code, your confusion here suggests that you don't understand "Separation of Concerns". Separate the process of getting information from the process of displaying that information. When the user enters new information, add that to javascript array or object of information you got from the server and also send that off to the server to be updated in the database. Then run the display function again using the updated information to include the new information. Ideally, the display process will use existing markup if it can, rather than deleting it all and recreating it all just to add one item. [Here's a very basic example (click here).](http://jsbin.com/umUhuWE/1/edit) Ideally, you would take this concept and expand on it to make it optimally efficient and organized.

Here's the sample code from my jsbin. Please keep in mind this is just to get you started.

```
var info = [1,2,3,4,5]; //this is what you got from your ajax call to the server

function render(element, info) {
  //this is a lazy system that recreates/replaces all the markup each time. I suggest doing this more efficiently, but that is work for you to do :)
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var len = info.length;
  for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = info[i];
    frag.appendChild(p);
  }
  element.innerHTML = '';
  element.appendChild(frag);
}

var targetElem = document.getElementById('targetElem');

render(targetElem, info);

var addButton = document.getElementById('add');
var input = document.getElementById('infoInput');
addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  info.push(input.value); //update the information
  render(targetElem, info); //render the updated information
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should give you success.

```
success: function(userinfos) {
                 $("#users").append($('<tr><td>'+userinfos+'</td></tr>'))
                 display_message("user added");
               }
```

---

```
 $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "ht.tp://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?age="+ ageData +"&occasion="+ 
occasionData     +"&relationship="+ forData +"#",

success: function (response) {

    $("#testDIV").html(response);
}
});
```